# What’s the German equivalent of the Latin phrase: “Non ducor, duco”?

Tags: phrase-request, latin

What’s the German equivalent of the following Latin phrase:

> Non ducor, duco. – I am not led; I lead.

Conditions:

1. It does not have to carry the same *literal* meaning.
2. It should carry the same badass vibe associated with the original Latin saying.

Comment: I did not know that Latin phrases could carry a 'badass vibe'. Somehow, my Latin teachers hid this from me over nine years of Latin at school. So, thank you for enlightening me now! Better late than never.

Comment: After 10 minutes of trying to find good German phrases... hm... could you add some context, e.g. a typical situation where you would use this?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether there is a common agreement of the conotation and even the pure meaning leaves room for interpretation. The most general counterpiece in my opinion is *__Ich_ bin hier der Chef/bestimme, wo es lang geht*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a snappy phrase. The latin "ducor/duco" leads you to the impression you had to use first person, passive voice and indicative which is all super-lame in German.

For those reasons German mottos are given in impersonal imperative usually.

> Nicht führen lassen, führen!

That's a snappy phrase a soccer trainer or other motivational coach would use.

Answer (score 10):

German expression has it the other way round:

> Ich mache nicht, ich lasse machen

This might at first look a bit different from the original Latin, but means the same in today's working society.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, it *is* pretty different from the original Latin, but this works anyway. I've accepted @Janka's answer because, well, it kinda sounds more "badass" (a crudely defined term, I agree). Once again, I *really* appreciate this answer (I upvoted ^_^) and I hope to bump into more of your answers in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

"Wo ich bin ist vorne." Das Motto der Schweizer Späher.

Nicht genau übersetzt aber mindestens genauso badass.

Answer (score 4):

It is a motto of São Paulo (Brazil), in [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo) it has translation "Ich werde nicht geführt, ich führe"

Comment: To account for the "badass vibe", it should read *Man führt mich nicht, ich führe!* That's a real badass babe we have then.

Comment: @Janka yes it sounds better